# Questions related to compact complex curves, symmetric products and linear independence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact complex curve and let $L$ be a very ample line bundle over $X$. Denote by $C_n( X )$ the configuration space of $n$ (ordered) distinct points on $X$.

Given distinct points $z_1$, ..., $z_n$ on $X$, so that they form an element in $C_n( X )$, let

$$p_1 = [ (z_2, ... ,z_n) ],$$
$$p_2 = [ (z_1, z_3, ..., z_n) ],$$
$$\vdots$$
$$p_n = [ (z_1, z_2, ..., z_{n-1}) ]$$ in the symmetric product $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}X$ of n-1 copies of X.

Note that on the product $X^{n-1}$ of $n-1$ copies of $X$, one can pullback $L$ using the first projection map, and so on, then pullback $L$ using the ($n-1$)-st projection map, and then tensor all these line bundles together. This defines a line bundle on $X^{n-1}$, which descends to a line bundle on $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}X$. Let us denote the resulting line bundle, say, by $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}( L )$.

Question 1: if $L$ is very ample, is $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}( L )$ also very ample? (I would think so)

If this is indeed the case, then $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}( L )$ induces an embedding from $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}X$ into a complex projective space, namely

$$PH^0(\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}X, \operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}( L ))^*,$$

the projectivization of the dual of the space of holomorphic sections of $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}( L )$). Let us denote this embedding by $f$.

Question 2: Is it true that $f(p_1)$, ..., $f(p_n)$ are linearly independent, as points in complex projective space?

I have a feeling this is true. I also ask similar questions if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are instead defined by:

$$p_1 = [(z_1,\ldots,z_1)],$$
$$p_2 = [(z_2,\ldots,z_2)],$$
$$\vdots$$
$$p_n = [(z_n,\ldots,z_n)]$$

in $\operatorname{Sym}^{n-1}X$.

I know that the answers to my questions are yes in the case where $X = P^1(\mathbb{C})$ and $L = \mathcal{O}(1)$. Indeed, the linear independence statement amounts to the fact that the Lagrange basis (related to Lagrange interpolation) is linearly independent (so indeed a basis). And for the modified $p_i$, this amounts to the well known fact that $n$ distinct points on a rational normal curve of degree $n-1$ in $P^{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$ are linearly independent, itself equivalent to the non-vanishing of a Vandermonde determinant, from an algebraic point of view.

I wonder if my statements still hold if $X$ is any compact complex curve of genus $g$ and if $L$ is any very ample line bundle on $X$.